# Parsing an XML file using Element Tree

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I have a large number of .xml files (about 70) and i need to extract some co-ordinates from them. 
Apparently the best way to do this is to parse the xml file using element tree. I am new to python (very very new!) and am having a difficult time understanding all of the documentation which comes with element tree! 
I was wondering if anyone had any code where they have used element tree or if anyone could explain to me how to go about it.. 
Thank you!

This is a sample from my XML file..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <lev:Leveringsinformatie xmlns:lev="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/klic/20080722/leveringsinfo">
  <lev:Version>1.5</lev:Version> 
  <lev:Klicnummer>10G179900</lev:Klicnummer> 
  <lev:Ordernummer>0065491624</lev:Ordernummer> 
  <lev:RelatienummerGrondroerder>0000305605</lev:RelatienummerGrondroerder> 
  <lev:Leveringsvolgnummer>1</lev:Leveringsvolgnummer> 
  <lev:Meldingsoort>Graafmelding</lev:Meldingsoort> 
  <lev:DatumTijdAanvraag>2010-08-10T11:43:02.779+02:00</lev:DatumTijdAanvraag> 
  <lev:KlantReferentie>1207-0132-030 - 6</lev:KlantReferentie> 
- <lev:Locatie axisLabels="x y" srsDimension="2" srsName="epsg:28992" uomLabels="m m">
- <gml:exterior xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
- <gml:LinearRing>
  <gml:posList>137800.0 484217.0 137796.0 484222.0 137832.0 483757.0 138178.0 483752.0 138174.0 484222.0 137800.0 484217.0</gml:posList> 
  </gml:LinearRing>
  </gml:exterior>
  </lev:Locatie>
- <lev:Pngformaat>
- <lev:OmsluitendeRechthoek xmlns:ns4="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/klic/20080722/madt" xmlns:bis="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/klic/20080722/klicnetbeheerdersinformatieservicetypes" xmlns:ns0="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/klic/20080722/gias" xmlns:ns7="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/klic/20080722/klicnetbeheerdersinformatieservicetypes" xmlns:madt="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/klic/20080722/madt" xmlns:gia="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/klic/20080722/gias" xmlns:klic="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/20080722/klic" xmlns:b="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/klic/20080722/bundelingtypes" xmlns:ns9="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/klic/20081010/bmkltypes" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ns1="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/20080722/klic" xmlns:a="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/klic/20080722/bundelingservicetypes" xmlns:bmkl="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/klic/20081010/bmkltypes" xmlns:ns3="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ns8="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/klic/20080722/knts">
- <gml:Envelope srsDimension="2" srsName="epsg:28992">
  <gml:lowerCorner>137796 483752</gml:lowerCorner> 
  <gml:upperCorner>138178 484222</gml:upperCorner> 
  </gml:Envelope>
  </lev:OmsluitendeRechthoek>
  <lev:PixelsBreed>5348</lev:PixelsBreed> 
  <lev:PixelsHoog>6580</lev:PixelsHoog> 
  </lev:Pngformaat>
- <lev:NetbeheerderLeveringen>
- <lev:NetbeheerderLevering>
  <lev:RelatienummerNetbeheerder>0000578695</lev:RelatienummerNetbeheerder> 
  <lev:Bedrijfsnaam>Gemeente Almere</lev:Bedrijfsnaam> 
  <lev:BedrijfsnaamAfkorting>Gemeente Almere</lev:BedrijfsnaamAfkorting>
```

I need to extract the lower and upper corner co-ordinates (lowerCorner/upperCorner)

Update: Here is my full script:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import sys, string, os, arcgisscripting
gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)

workspace = "D:/J040083"
gp.workspace = workspace

for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(workspace): # returms root, dirs, and files
    for filename in filenames:
        filename_split = os.path.splitext(filename) # filename and extensionname (extension in [1])
        filename_zero = filename_split[0]
        extension = str.upper(filename_split[1])

        try:
            first_2_letters = str.upper(filename_zero[0] + filename_zero[1])
        except:
            first_2_letters = "XX"

        if first_2_letters == "LI" and extension == ".XML":
            tree = ET.parse(workspace)
            print tree.find('//{http://www.opengis.net/gml}lowerCorner').text
            print tree.find('//{http://www.opengis.net/gml}upperCorner').text
```

I am now getting the error:

Message File Name   Line    Position
Traceback
        D:\J040083\TXT_EXTRACTION.py    32
    parse   C:\Python25\Lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py    862
    parse   C:\Python25\Lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py    579
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/J040083'

and now i am REALLY confused because i am able to access these files with a different script which is almost exactly the same as this one!!

Comment: Just so we're all on the same page, have you read the [ElementTree documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)? That's a reference document but there are examples sprinkled throughout the page. For an intro, the [ElementTree Overview](http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm) page might be helpful too.

Comment: Embarrassingly yes i have read it! I just don't really understand it..

Comment: @Alice: I suggest you post a small realistic snippet from an XML file you want to parse and specify the data you want to reach. You can do it by editing your own post.

Comment: I did try that but it just shows up in my question not in the correct format.. so instead of having the comments it just had the numbers!

Comment: @Alice: it's worth the time taking a few minutes to learn the SO formatting rules. Update it, and maybe another member with more experience can fix it up for you (and later you can see how it's done)

Comment: hmm.. i tried! It didn't seem to work though! Im sorry for my ignorance!

Comment: @Alice: this doesn't look like xml at all :) paste the xml and format it as code

Comment: ahh yes.. stupid! there you go!

Comment: @Alice Duff - if you're going to be doing a lot of work with GML then I'd recommend reading up on XML. GML can get fairly complex and you'll be pleased you got the XML fundamentals sorted out. I can't recommend any tutorials as it's been a while since I've looked at them, but avoid W3Schools (NOT linked with W3, who actually write the spec!) as they're frequently inaccurate. This is the first result that isn't W3Schools: http://www.learn-xml-tutorial.com/

Comment: GML?! Basically i have hundreds and hundreds of .png files and i need to convert them into a format readable by ArcMap (a GIS program). So i have made a script which converts them into shapefiles and loads them into the programme - but i need to write another script which extracts the co-ordinates from the XML files which come with them in order to place them on the correct place on the map i am making!

Comment: @Alice Duff - your XML file is GML http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/gml "an XML grammar for expressing geographical features". If you only need to extract coordinates then you'll be OK, but if you need to any other manipulation of the XML then GML can be quite daunting.

Comment: ok! Brilliant! Could you point me in the direction of any documentation/code which could help me extract these coordinates!

Comment: @Alice: this is not a complete XML sample (for example the tag `</lev:OmsluitendeRechthoek>` doesn't close anything opening I can see in your sample). Please post a more complete sample

Comment: There you go - the rest of the code after this section is just peoples names and phone numbers etc!

Comment: @Alice, in your updated script the error is from `tree = ET.parse(workspace)`.  workspace is just a directory name, not a file name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ElementTree can be tricky when namespaces are involved.  The element you are looking for are named `<gml:lowerCorner>` and `<gml:upperCorner>`.  Searching higher in the XML data, `gml` is defined as an XML namespace: `xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"`.  The way to find a subelement of the XML tree is as follows:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
print tree.find('//{http://www.opengis.net/gml}lowerCorner').text
print tree.find('//{http://www.opengis.net/gml}upperCorner').text
```

#### Output

```
137796 483752
138178 484222
```

### Explanation

Using ElementTree's [XPath](http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm) support, `//` selects all subelements on all levels of the tree.  ElementTree uses `{url}tag` notation for a tag in a specific namespace.  `gml`'s URL is `http://www.opengis.net/gml`.  `.text` retrieves the data in the element.

Note that `//` is a shortcut to finding a nested node.  The full path of `upperCorner` in ElementTree's syntax is actually:

```
{http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/klic/20080722/leveringsinfo}Pngformaat/{http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/klic/20080722/leveringsinfo}OmsluitendeRechthoek/{http://www.opengis.net/gml}Envelope/{http://www.opengis.net/gml}upperCorner
```

Comment: +1 for a good explanation. Only thing I'm not sure of is if there is max 1 gml:Envelope per document, perhaps Alice can comment?

Comment: oh hurray hurray!! It works!! The rest of the XML is just peoples names and email addresses - so i think the section i showed you is the only gml one - if thats what you mean james? I now have to save the output in a predefined excel file! Thank you all so much!

Comment: If the answer is acceptable, please check it as accepted.  Glad to be of help. :)

Comment: Hi mark! I had to uncheck your answer because i have a new question - or should i just post it as a new question?

Answer (score 2):

Using ElementTree is very simple, basically you create an object parsed from a file, find elements by name or path, and get their text or attribute.

In your case it's a bit more complicated because you have namespaces in your file, so we have to transform the path from the form `ns:tag` to the form `{uri}tag`. This the aim of the `transform_path` function

```
NS_MAP = {
    'http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/klic/20080722/leveringsinfo' : 'lev',
    'http://www.opengis.net/gml' : 'gml',
}
INV_NS_MAP = {v:k for k, v in NS_MAP.items()} #inverse ns_map 
#for python2: INV_NS_MAP = dict((v,k) for k, v in NS_MAP.iteritems())

#ElementTree expect tags in form {uri}tag, but it would be a pain to have complete uri for eache tag
def transform_path (path):
    res = ''
    tags = path.split('/')
    for tag in tags:
      ns, tag = tag.split(':')
      res += "{"+INV_NS_MAP[ns]+"}"+tag+'/'
    return res

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
doc = tree.getroot()

lowerCorner = doc.find(transform_path("lev:Pngformaat/lev:OmsluitendeRechthoek/gml:Envelope/gml:lowerCorner"))
upperCorner = doc.find(transform_path("lev:Pngformaat/lev:OmsluitendeRechthoek/gml:Envelope/gml:upperCorner"))
print (lowerCorner.text)         # Print coordinates
print (upperCorner.text)         # Print coordinates

#for python2: print elem.text
```

Running the script with you file will give the following output:

```
137796 483752
138178 484222
```

Comment: Thanks Charles, I am trying to run your code but it keeps giving me the error "Invalid Syntax" for the final line!

Comment: im having some trouble making this script work.. Now i get an "Invalid Syntax" error for the second from last line..?

Comment: I think it should work i just dont understand how to make it work with my data - i will try doing some research and hopefully i will understand!!

Comment: I made a small script that reads the coordinates of your file